# md-datepicker not rendering calendar correctly

Tags: css, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I cannot get the md-datepicker to render correctly. I have followed the instructions by initializing the model in the controller to: `new Date()`, but when calendar opens I don't see days, like on the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot].

However when I scroll up after a few seconds, days start to appear normally

[image]

I used the angular 1.6.1 and the ngMaterial 1.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add

```
angular.module('App', []).config(function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I degraded the angular-material version to 1.1.0 and it works as expected.